# Gari as subtitutes for tapioca

Tags: substitutions, cake, flour

I used to make a lot of cakes using tapioca flour. Now I've moved to another country and rarely stumbled upon the flour in the supermarket. Last time I found gari which also made from cassava. Can I substitute gari for tapioca? Can I put it in food processor first to make the texture more similar? From what I've read, usually gari's mixed with water to make porridge, but I don't have a lot of ideas in how to use it (other than all my tapioca flour recipes).

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Most western substitutes call for using Corn Starch instead since the two have similar binding properties. For example see this:

http://www.buzzle.com/articles/tapioca-flour-substitute.html

Garri/Gari may seem closer to home, since it made from Tapioca as well (aka Casava), but it is a different composition than Tapioca flour. While Tapioca flour is primarily starch, Garri's composition is somewhat the **opposite** since Garri is what remains after the starchy water is drained from mashed-up, oiled Tapioca.

As suggested, look for starch-based flours, your best option is Corn Starch available in most countries.

Sources for my research:

On Tapioca Starch:
http://www.bobsredmill.com/blog/healthy-living/what-is-it-wednesday-tapioca-flourstarch/

On Garri: Wikipedia :)

Comment: Hello, what a well-researched answer. Will try to replace them with corn starch then, and will take a note of the difference of the resulted cakes. I should find gari recipes to use my gari, never cooked with one before.

Answer (score 2):

Gari is made from kassava but it is the opposite of tapioca. That is, tapioca is the starch squeezed from kassava, and gari is the left-over fibre. It is only fibre and has little or no starch.